# Can i use Hangouts Chat API for application not use for bots?

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Can I use Hangouts Chat API for a application like someone sign in this application and get dm or rooms for my application? I means i don't went to create a bot ,but i went use this API to get info from Hangouts Chat and send messages.

Comment: Can be closed as Too Broad or Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking if you can use the API to write your own client. If so, no, this is not possible. According to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/service-accounts) `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot` is the *only* scope available to the Hangouts Chat API and:

> This scope only works for service accounts—you can't use this scope to authenticate using end-user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with thrid party API, You can try [Hangup Bot](https://github.com/xmikos/hangupsbot)